# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-cardview

I know this question is asked a few times, but they all are related to eclipse and I am using Android Studio and thus those answers didn't help me. I am trying to include CardView in one of my fragments for a recycler view item. The XML code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/cv" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/mainBodyText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/mainBodyText"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the `build.gradle` file of module `app` below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

And on running I get the following exception:

```
08-02 14:37:07.693  10102-10102/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 10102
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.myapp.myapp.adapter.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:29)
            at com.myapp.myapp.adapter.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:17)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5116)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4416)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4326)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1955)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1364)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1327)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:556)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2713)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3011)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2102)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1859)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnabl
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: post more stack trace there must be more..and it will contain the actual reason

Comment: @AdityaChauhan Sorry, this is the only stacktrace I got from there.

Comment: There should be a `Caused by`

Comment: @user4847410 There was not. It is trimmed of :(

Comment: there must be series of logs that will start with "caused by" check again..inflate exception generally has the real reason behind crash in series of logs that have a lot of caused by s and the last caused by has the exact reasn behind crash

Comment: Binary line 10 means the starting of card view has some problem

Comment: Yes Inflate is thrown problem the real problem is a deeper one

Comment: I will try to get it

Comment: There seems to be a limit with logcat stacktrace which cannot be overcome,  Can you check the current logcat and tell a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid we may not

Comment: Connect phone with PC and goto where adb is type `adb logcat` and click your app and see the logcat

Comment: Got any information??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this after days of effort. It was pretty simple solution anyway. The point here is, when inflating the view I needed to use the view's parent's context. Earlier I was using the application's context. The new code looks like this:

```
@Override
public SearchItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new SearchItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_item, parent, false));
}
```

Earlier it was:

```
@Override
public SearchItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new SearchItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_item, parent, false));
}
```

Where the `context` was passed from the activity and it was obtained using `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: You are totally right bro. This was a pretty annoying issue, because I was using the application context with CardView v 23.4.0 and all was working fine, until now, that I'm using v 25.3.1 and it is crashing, so I used the parent context instead of the app context and it is working great.